# Wit.ai Not Parsing Data to Chat Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, messenger, wit.ai

I am having some problems with my modification of wit.ai's messenger.js on GitHub. I added some API calls to get real time weather but I am having trouble getting the result into the bot's reply (context.forecast). The context.forecast line is not able to 'see' my weather data it seems.

Most relevant line is:

```
context.forecast = 'Todays forecast is: ' + hourlyWeather +' in ' + location;
```

hourlyWeather has data such as "Light rain until this evening." but the bots reply leaves it out.

Here is the relevant code, I am hoping I just have something in the wrong place/order as I am new to Node. I appreciate the help.

```
// Our bot actions
const actions = {
send({sessionId}, {text}, request) {
//const {context, entities} = request;
// Our bot has something to say!
// Let's retrieve the Facebook user whose session belongs to
const recipientId = sessions[sessionId].fbid;

if (recipientId) {
  // Yay, we found our recipient!
  // Let's forward our bot response to her.
  // We return a promise to let our bot know when we're done sending
  return fbMessage(recipientId, text)
  .then(() => null)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(
      'Oops! An error occurred while forwarding the response to',
      recipientId,
      ':',
      err.stack || err
    );
  });
} else {
  console.error('Oops! Couldn\'t find user for session:', sessionId);
  // Giving the wheel back to our bot
  return Promise.resolve()
 }
},



// You should implement your custom actions here
  // See https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart



//Problems start here. ----------------

  getForecast({context, entities}) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var location = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location')
      if (location) {
         // we should call a weather API here



        //API call to convert city name to longitude latitude
        const requestw = require('request'),url = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q='+location+'&format=json'

        request(url, (error, response, body)=> {
          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            const fbResponse = JSON.parse(body)
            //console.log("Got a response: ", fbResponse)
            //convert JSON to array
            var arr = [];
            for(var x in fbResponse){
          arr.push(fbResponse[x]);
        }
            //find latitude and longitude in array and store for later weather api call
            if(arr[0].hasOwnProperty('lat')){
            var lat = arr[0].lat; 
        }
            if(arr[0].hasOwnProperty('lon')){
            var lon = arr[0].lon; 
        }
            console.log(lat, lon)

            //API call for weather status
            forecast.get([lat, lon], function(err, weather) {
            if(err) return console.dir(err);
            //console.dir(weather);
//Store weekly and daily report - Cant get to show up in forecast string. --------------
                console.log(weather.hourly.summary)
            var hourlyWeather = weather.hourly.summary;
                console.log(weather.daily.summary)
            var dailyWeather = weather.daily.summary;

            });
          } else {
            console.log("Got an error while grabbing coordinates of city: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode)
          }
        })

//Cant get hourlyWeather or dailyWeather to show here. Location works fine. Have tried declaring the variables elsewhere. -----------
        //context.forecast = hourlyWeather;
        context.forecast = 'Todays forecast is: ' + hourlyWeather +' in ' + location;



        delete context.missingLocation;
      } else {
        context.missingLocation = true;
        delete context.forecast;
      }
      return resolve(context);
    });
  }, 
};
```

The bot's reply would only read "Todays forecast is:  in Atlanta".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the hourlyWeather against the context.

```
var hourlyWeather = weather.hourly.summary;
context.hw = hourlyWeather;
```

Then access the weather via the context.

```
context.forecast = 'Todays forecast is: ' + context.hw +' in ' + location;
```